# High Sierra quicktime player does not support H.265 videos?

Tags: video, high-sierra, quicktime, encoding

So I upgraded my Mac to high Sierra and I was about the H.265 video encoding standard but when I encode a H.264 video to H.265 standard and then when I attempt to open the video using quick time player it shows "Quick Time player does not support these kind of videos"

So is this a problem that only I am experiencing or is this expected. I am running latest version of High Sierra by the way.

Comment: What is the file container? (AVI, MOV, MP4, MKV, etc)

Comment: FFmpeg h.265 .mp4 plays back fine here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“All iOS devices running iOS 11 and all Macs on High Sierra will support HEVC playback”
https://www.macrumors.com/guide/hevc-video-macos-high-sierra-ios-11

Use QuickTime to encode the video to HEVC/H.265 so you can ensure it is encoded to the correct standards. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/HLSAuthoringSpec/Requirements.html

I’m guessing you were encoding using Handbrake.